# Problem importing sip after successful installation

Tags: python, pip, python-3.6, python-venv, python-sip

Using python 3.6 in a virtual environment created by `python3 -m venv env_name` I need to use the python `sip` module.

I activate the venv by `source env_name/bin/activate`

I install this successfully by `pip install sip` which results in

```
Installing collected packages: packaging, sip
Successfully installed packaging-20.4 sip-5.4.0
```

Afterwards I can check that sip appears in pip by

```
$ pip list | grep sip
sip                           5.4.0
```

After all of this I try to use sip by opening python and importing it with the following error:

```
$ python 
Python 3.6.9 (default, Oct  8 2020, 12:12:24) 
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sip'
>>>
```

If I try the same outside the virtualenv it works fine, am I creating the virtualenv incorrectly?

edit: this is on ubuntu 18.04 LTS with python 3.6.9

Answer (score 2):

The sip module you would probably need is the module that supports pyqt5 or the latest pyqt6.

Installation with:

`pip install pyqt6-sip`

and the import with

`from PyQt6 import sip`

The stand-alone sip itself is a command line tool:
[Docu can be found here](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/sip/)

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you use `pip3` not `pip`. So you need you basically run `pip3 install sip`

Comment: why would i use pip3 in a python3 virtual env and not just pip? My understanding was that in the venv that pip should default to the venv python version, which is also verified by checking `pip -V`

Comment: Also for what it matters, just tried the same using `pip3 install sip` and then `python3` followed by `import sip` with the same results

Comment: @MortenNissov Activate your virtual env

Comment: My bad for not mentioning this but everything has been with the venv activated, I have edited the original post and added this as a comment